# How to delete Group Contact that is greyed out without an access to menu or drop down box?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I deleted my What's App Group Contact in error before deleting members first, however, several Admin members were automatically assigned by What's App to my created Group (now deleted by me).  Two of my members had full access to exiting group/deleting members and then deleting group. One member is still seeing Group Contact in What's App Contact List, has access to open Group Contact, under my group name created saw this "you're no longer a participant in this group", just below this, message sent by me and members numbers, but they have no access to anything to delete as its all greyed out.

Q1: What can be done to delete this Group Contact?

Q2: If they delete Group Contact from What's App Contact List, would this mean What's App would assign  three other Admin? As this was the original step done by me, hence why it got assigned to the three other members above.

I anxiously await your response.

Answer (score 0):

I was the sole admin on a group that I created in WhatsApp. I had to delete the group for some reasons. I removed the members one by one. At last I exited from the group. After that I deleted the group by clicking the options button by the side of menu button. It took sometime and disappeared.